# how to pivot rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of multiple rows, each column is the measurement of one id, I want to pivot the rows such as :

```
`
df = 1, meas11, meas12, meas13, t11,t12,t13, p1
     2, meas21, meas22, meas23, t21,t22,t23, p2`
```

into

```
`df = 1, meas11,t11,p1
     1, meas12,t12,p1
     1, meas13,t13,p1
     2, meas21,t21,p2
     2, meas22,t22,p2
     2, meas23,t23,p2`
```

how to Pivot a dataframe

Comment: Columns names missing in sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), but columns names are important, here working with `meas/t` with numbers:

```
print (df)
   id   meas1   meas2   meas3   t1   t2   t3   p
0   1  meas11  meas12  meas13  t11  t12  t13  p1
1   2  meas21  meas22  meas23  t21  t22  t23  p2

df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     stubnames=['meas','t'], 
                     i=['id','p'], 
                     j='tmp').droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id   p    meas    t
0   1  p1  meas11  t11
1   1  p1  meas12  t12
2   1  p1  meas13  t13
3   2  p2  meas21  t21
4   2  p2  meas22  t22
5   2  p2  meas23  t23
```